# Vintage movie about early modern humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, languages

Many years ago, I saw a movie that seemed to be set in the stone age. If my memory serves me correctly, the movie looked old even then, leaving it likely in the 1960s-80s range. Since it's been so long ago I don't remember very much at all about the movie other than I really liked it and it somehow stuck with me all this time.

The one central plot device I can remember is there was an artifact that granted you dominion over the clan. It may have been called the "Horns of Power." I tried search engine queries for "Horns of Power" but nothing seemed to be relevant to what I know it to be from. This itself leads me to believe it was not a very publicized production -- more of an artsy film.

Other things that are coming back to me as I write this: all the dialogue in the movie was in a fictional grunt language. And there was a cave scene where everyone was sleeping.

### Question

From my coarse reconstruction of the movie, can anyone hazard a guess as to what it was?

**Edit**: For some reason, I have a strong conviction that I remembered the Horns of Power as part of the story. The following is a pathetically crude dramatization of the scene as I remember it:

> *lengthy physical struggle*
>
> Old caveman loses, dies, or lies there limp.
>
> Stronger caveman gloats and says: "Behold the Horns of Power." as he
> holds up the sacred object over his head.

At this moment I thought to myself, wow ancient people sure did have reverence for horns. Wonder why. Fast forward 20 years and I'm *this close* to hiring a hypnotist to get to the bottom of it.

It may have been on the scify channel, one of those *really* obscure ones. But the production didn't seem that bad, so I'd still be surprised if it didn't have a decent following.

Comments have been helpful, thanks for all those!

Comment: The 13th Warrior movie has Vikings fighting primitive cave people whose leader wears The Horns of Power.  There's scenes in a cave complex with sleeping cavefolk.  They speak in a primitive sounding language.  1990s flick though.

Comment: @DoscoJones Oh my gosh that's right, Antonio Banderas, but I have that movie on DVD. I hope I didn't mistakenly supplant that onto this other movie which I think had protagonist cave people (all stone age).

Comment: Without the Horns, maybe Clan of the Cave Bear, or Quest for Fire?

Comment: The team that made Quest for Fire did serious work to invent the language used.  I think it is discussed on the dvd extras.  See https://www.anthonyburgess.org/quest-for-fire/quest-for-language/

Comment: @ArashHowaida if you think you might have misremembered and blended two films together check out one million years bc from 1966. Would certainly fit the vintage bill, has a language of grunts and a scene of cavement sleeping in a cave. Nothing like horns of power though. watch the trailer on youtube see if it looks familiar... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSYmJur0Npw

Comment: [*1 Million Years B.C.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Million_Years_B.C.)?

Comment: A long shot, but *Ironmaster*? The item of power is not a horn, but a sword, though. http://www.coolasscinema.com/2017/02/ironmaster-1983-review.html

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen The pelt-wearing man is ringing a bell, good lead, will investigate.

Comment: The details appear to contradict. If they speak in grunts, then how can one say "Behold the Horns of Power"?How would you know what it's called?

Comment: @Laurel Subtitles, maybe?

Comment: @skyjack they *did* use conch shells as horns, though.

Comment: Is your memory about "horns" as in the kind you blow on to make a sound, or just animal horns (not modified into a musical instrument)? I sort of assumed the latter but the comment above from @WolfieSmith seems to read it as the former, and the question in its current form doesn't really make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure this is a distorted memory of  either [One Million B.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Million_B.C.) (1940)  or the remake [One Million Years B.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Million_Years_B.C.) (1966)

A language of grunts, and various power struggles for leadership of the tribe

Early in the film, the tribe trap a warthog in a pit and kill it. A caveman rips out a tooth from the beast and brandishes it triumphantly.

An old man falls into the pit and lies there limp. The tribe just abandon him.

I don't know if the tooth is important to the rest of the plot, but this is probably what you are remembering.